# Reference help for "fuzzy mathematics"

Tags: reference-request, fuzzy-logic

I want to study Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy logic self. For that what would be better book to start from basic?

Comment: What level are you at, and why are you trying to learn the topic? It helps people recommend books if they know why you are trying to learn something. For example, if you are looking for applications, there might be one book, theory another.

Comment: I'm looking for applications@ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 3):

It is still difficult to make suggestions, but here are some items for exploring (you can peruse these on Amazon):

- Fuzzy Mathematics: An Introduction for Engineers and Scientists, John N. Mordeson, Premchand S. Nair
- Fuzzy Sets and Systems: Theory and Applications (Mathematics in Science & Engineering), Didier J. Dubois
- Computational Intelligence in Games (Studies in Fuzziness and Soft Computing), Norio Baba

Additonally, look at the list here for other pointers to books, authors and subjects:

- (Check out the list here and then peruse each and see if it is what you are looking for (http://www.alibris.com/search/books/subject/Fuzzy-mathematics)

Comment: And there's "fuzzy logic"!!! ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: I'm rather fuzzy on the entire topic! :-)

Answer (score 0):

[This pdf](https://www.studiecd.dk/cahiers_techniques/Fuzzy_logic.pdf) is the best intro I've read. here is the name to google in case the link rots:

Cahier technique no 191

Fuzzy logic