# Book request: fuzzy sets and logic

Tags: book-recommendation, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

There are requests for this topic already, though I am looking for a particular kind of book on the topic. I got part of the way through Trillas' and Eciolaza's book *Fuzzy Logic: An Introductory Course for Engineering Students*. My issue with this book is I think written in its title; it is written in the style of an Engineering textbook, and not in the style of a Mathematics textbook. Specifically, I find the the order of consequence often vague, using terms without properly defining them and at times find it difficult to interpret a clear definition of other terms.

So I am looking for a book on the matter that is written for mathematicians / logicians, with well-formed definitions, well structured arguments (lemmas with properly articulated axioms) etc.

The book also needs to be available in electronic format and suited to self-study

Any recommendations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference help for "fuzzy mathematics"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373665/reference-help-for-fuzzy-mathematics)

Comment: From a logician's perspective, fuzzy logic is *meaningless* in a rigorous sense. There is no rigorous formalization of fuzzy logic that *actually makes sense as a logic for reasoning*. You may be able to use some fuzzy notions of fuzzy logic as *heuristics* in optimization algorithms or other things, but there is no true logical backing for them.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite book on Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic is the text-book:

George J. Klir and Bo Yuan:

Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic: Theory and Applications

(1995, Pearson Education)

It is a well-written book and I love it.

[Klir & Yuan : Book on Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic (Pearson, 1995)](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Klir-Fuzzy-Sets-and-Fuzzy-Logic-Theory-and-Applications/PGM73001.html)
Since you reminded me of this topic, I plan to read this book again!
[image: Klir & Yuan - Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic]

Comment: I was hoping to check that book out. Unfortunately I can't find it in an electronic format. The Pearson link *seems* to be an electronic format (or at least an ad for some kind of available product), but the title doesn't actually show up in their list of etextbooks.